# PHP Object Creation and Memory Usage

Tags: php, object, memory

A basic dummy class:

```
class foo
{
    var $bar = 0;
    function foo() {}
    function boo() {}
}
echo memory_get_usage();
echo "\n";
$foo = new foo();
echo memory_get_usage();
echo "\n";
unset($foo);
echo memory_get_usage();
echo "\n";
$foo = null; 
echo memory_get_usage();
echo "\n";
```

Outputs:

```
$ php test.php
353672
353792
353792
353792
```

Now, I know that PHP docs say that memory won't be freed until it is needed (hitting the ceiling).  However, I wrote this up as a small test, because I've got a much longer task, using a much bigger object, with many instances of that object.  And the memory just climbs, eventually running out and stopping execution.  Even though these large objects do take up memory, since I destroy them after I'm done with each one (serially), it should not run out of memory (unless a single object exhausts the entire space for memory, which is not the case).

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any circular references that could stop the garbage collector from doing its task?

I ran a quick test creating 1,000,000 objects and the memory wasn't eaten up:

```
class foo
{
    var $bar = 0;
    function foo() {}
    function boo() {}
}

echo memory_get_usage() . "\n";

$foo = new foo();
unset($foo);

echo memory_get_usage() . "\n";

for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++)
{
    $var = 'foo' . $i; // Use a different variable name each time
    $$var = new foo();
    unset($$var);
}

echo memory_get_usage() . "\n";
```

65080 65384 65568 <-- A very tiny increase for 1,000,000 objects created and destroyed

Comment: On 5.2.8 on Windows I got 62360 62528 62712 which was even smaller :)

Answer (score 2):

PHP's support for objects & classes aren't very efficient in ver 5.2 (nor have they been in the past), but the upcoming 5.3 and 6.0 are a big overhaul in regards to class and object usage and you will see speed and memory improvements in them both.

I have also written some bare bone frameworks in PHP 5.2.x and found the memory usage surprising bloated also.  Although considering how cheap powerful multi-core CPUs are and ram is, I would say keep coding in a manner that makes the most sense to you and creates a more RAD setup.

If using Smarty or Drupal makes your work project finish faster, then use them, or whatever custom stuff you do.  Don't let today's poor memory/speed usage turn you off to OOP or frameworks because tomorrow's version has some noteworthy improvements (real world benchmarks have shown a 30% speed improvement on the same code).

PS: There's something wrong with your setup, I ran the same code on Apache /w PHP 5.2.8 on Windows XP and got: 60872 61080 61080 61080

Comment: Are you suggesting that hardware can solve this problem?  I have the exact same issue where memory climbs and climbs until the script crashes, all the while CPU is at 100% (dual core 3.06 Ghz intel, 8 Gigs Ram).  I have thought about throwing hardware at my problem.  Will a quad core double the speed this takes to execute? Will a Hex core quadruple it? (given the same amount of RAM for each scenario)

Comment: When you have a scenario where memory usage creeps up, then a bug or a leak exists that's not being cleaned up.  You'll have to look deeper to find any helps with that, but the way 95% of people deal with that is to reboot the script/session/webserver/server.

Creeping memory usage is the cause of most slowdowns & instability in server set ups, and sometimes there's just no fix, aside from running the latest copy of your webserver, PHP, MySQL, etc and hope the bug exists there and was fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a revised example with circular references:

```
<?php
class foo
{
    public $bar = 0;
    function foo(){}
    function boo(){}
}

echo memory_get_usage() . "\n";

$foo = new foo();
unset($foo);

echo memory_get_usage() . "\n";

$arr = array(new foo());

for ($i = 1; $i < 1000000; $i += 2)
{
    $arr[$i] = new foo();
    $arr[$i - 1] = new foo();
    unset($arr[$i], $arr[$i - 1]);
}

echo memory_get_usage() . "\n";

for ($i = 1; $i < 1000000; $i += 2)
{
    $arr[$i] = new foo();
    $arr[$i - 1] = new foo();
    $arr[$i]->bar = $arr[$i-1];
    $arr[$i-1]->bar = $arr[$i];
    unset($arr[$i], $arr[$i - 1]);
}

echo memory_get_usage() . "\n";
```

Outputs with PHP 5.3.6 (cli):

```
644392
644392
644848
1628592
```