# creating new object again and again is bad practice . why ?

Tags: php-5.3

I heard numerous times that creating object for same database classes again and again is the bad practice.i really dont understand why is it so . Please somebody explain .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bad idea in general , not just for database classes.
The more objects you have , the more memory being used to maintain your application.
For instance , take a look at: [PHP Object Creation and Memory Usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469386/php-object-creation-and-memory-usage)

Hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

http://particletree.com/notebook/object-oriented-php-memory-concerns/

Have a look at that link to see how much memory is required to create an object (which has only 1 variable). **Heavy class means bigger object**. Having several memory-hungry scripts and a certain level of user base are enough to take up all memory in no time.

With regards to database classes, depending on whether the class opens up a connection on initialisation, as both the web server and database server have settings for maximum number of connections. The more objects you create, the more connections would be created which is not a good practice. One connection per database, if you can. If your database classes reuses the connection or use lazy initialisation to create the connection when required, you will still face the aforementioned memory problem.

To put it simply, reuse your objects (and your database connection).